# Zero or One to One Relationship EF Core using Fluent Api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.0

If I have the model:

```
public class User
{
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public string SomeInfo { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder
            .Property(t => t.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
}
```

When I run my test below it shows that the Account is removed from the user but not from the database

```
[Test]
public async Task GivenAUser_WhenISetTheAccountToNull_ThenTheAccountIsRemovedFromTheDatabase()
{
    Guid userId;
    using (DbContext dbContext = GetDbContext())
    {
        UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository(dbContext);
        User newUser = new User
        {
            SomeInfo = "SomeInfo",
            Account = new Account
            {
                Name = "Name"
            }
        };
        await userRepository.SaveAsync(newUser);
        userId = newUser.Id;
    }

    using (DbContext dbContext = GetDbContext())
    {
        UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository(dbContext);
        User user = await userRepository.GetAsync(userId);
        user.Account = null;
        await userRepository.SaveAsync(user);
    }

    User userDb;
    int userAccountsCount;
    using (DbContext dbContext = GetDbContext())
    {
        UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository(dbContext);
        userAccountsCount = await dbContext.Set<UserAccount>().CountAsync();
        userDb = await userRepository.GetAsync(userId);
    }

    Assert.That(userDb.Account, Is.EqualTo(null)); // true
    Assert.That(userAccountsCount, Is.EqualTo(0)); // false
}
```

I've tried to create a UserEntityTypeConfiguration to set cascade delete on an optional field, but I can't seem to get it working for an optional field.

```
public class UserEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder
            .Property(t => t.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Account)
            .WithOne()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask do you need a one to one relationship as strictly speaking they are advised against, as a database will only see it as a one to many anyways. Databases don't actually know what a one to one is. What is the one to one doing?

Comment: I've got classes that I was hoping to map to the database.  Are you suggesting that I should have a user table that has the account name and map that to two classes?

Comment: Well id its a one to one could you not just put them under the same class?

Comment: I want to keep them seperate.  If I put Name under user, you would think it was the users name, rather than the accounts name. it made sense to have an Account object that had a name

Comment: would it be possible to take a look at the classes?

Comment: they are at the top in the example?

Comment: Just so I can get it right, this is essentially a User Table that has an account?

Comment: yeah, but the user can exist without an account, and the account can't exist without a user.

Comment: Could you not just have the one table and set it to null if they don't have an account?

Comment: and map it to two classes? Is that possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155905/discussion-between-max-and-chris31389).

Answer (score 0):

You are not removing Account entity. You are just broking the relationship with User.  Also what you configured in Fluent API is "Delete related Account entity if the User entity deleted." Instead of this.

```
using (DbContext dbContext = GetDbContext())
{
    UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository(dbContext);
    User user = await userRepository.GetAsync(userId);
    user.Account = null;
    await userRepository.SaveAsync(user);
}
```

You should remove the entity itself.

```
using (DbContext dbContext = GetDbContext())
{
    UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository(dbContext);
    User user = await userRepository.GetAsync(userId);
    Account acc = user.Account;
    dbContext.Entity(acc).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

If you want to use repository pattern, you are free to implement your own solution.

Comment: Hi Okan,  this looks awesome.  If I load the user, then remove the account then pass the user to the repository to be saved, when I get the user so that I can get the account to delete, it reloads the user and overrides any changes i've made.  Do you know how I can avoid that and just get the account relating to the user directly?

Comment: About accessing directly. I recommend you to configure one-to-one relationship to access User of the Account Entity in LINQ query. like `db.Account.Where(p=>p.User.Id==userId);`   or you can set FK for both side and use it as well. I don't understand about what you trying to achieve when updating user. If you deleted Account entity successfully, it should not load it again.